# I have 2 dropdownbuttons and i cant make one depend on the other one

Tags: android, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, dropdownbutton

I have 2 dropdown buttons, which one have a list with an 'id' and a 'name' and i need to make like when i choose a option from one dropdown button only appear a certain number of options in the second dropdown button.
In the image 4 if i choose a option in the first dropdown button it would show only like 4 options in the second dropdown button(image 5). im kinda new to this, idk if this is to much to ask. sorry.

[the class of the lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eREth.png)

[the lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO4jN.png)

[the dropdownbuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpN3U.png)

[the 2 dropdown buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wYUC.png)

[the second dropdown button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz0xG.png)

```
DropdownButton<DisciplinaResumo>(
            value: selectedDisciplina,
            onChanged: (DisciplinaResumo? newValue) {
              setState(
                () {
                  selectedDisciplina = newValue!;
                  disciplinaController.text = selectedDisciplina.toString();
                },
              );
            },
            items: disciplinaResumo.map(
              (DisciplinaResumo resumo) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<DisciplinaResumo>(
                  value: resumo,
                  child: new Text(
                    resumo.name,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ).toList(),
          ),
          DropdownButton<ModuloResumo>(
            value: selectedModulo,
            onChanged: (ModuloResumo? newValue) {
              setState(
                () {
                  selectedModulo = newValue!;
                  moduloController.text = selectedModulo.toString();
                },
              );
            },
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code here? it will be more easy to copy paste to suggest you a solution! :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter the dropdown items, you can use the `where` method of `Iterable`! https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html

For example you can implement a where for your ModuloResumo based on the discipline selection:

```
moduloResumo.where((modulo) {
  if (selectedDiscipline == null) {
    return true;
  } else {
    switch(selectedDiscipline!.id) {
      case 1:
        return modulo.id < 4;
      case 2:
        return modulo.id > 4 && modulo.id < 6;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

to include the same in your code (with a sample of a filtering) you can do something like that, the filtering logic depends on how you want to filter!

```
DropdownButton<ModuloResumo>(
  value: selectedModule,
  onChanged: (ModuloResumo? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      selectedModule = newValue;
    });
  },
  items:
  moduloResumo.where((modulo) {
    if (selectedDiscipline == null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      switch (selectedDiscipline!.id) {
        case 1:
          return modulo.id < 4;
        case 2:
          return modulo.id > 4 && modulo.id < 6;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }).map<DropdownMenuItem<ModuloResumo>>(
    (resumo) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<ModuloResumo>(
        value: resumo,
        child: Text(resumo.name),
      );
    },
  ).toList(),
),
```

you can find an interactive sample here https://dartpad.dev/1e8bc3f4a341ceb75c6644848d7d1c21

also you may need to clear your selectedModule when you select a discipline, in order to avoid having a not valid selection (ie if the module should not appear for the selected discipline)

```
onChanged: (DisciplinaResumo? newValue) {
  setState(() {
    selectedDiscipline = newValue;
    //todo check if the selectedModule is still valid or set selecetModule = null;
  });
},
```

Comment: thank u a lot, will try that :)